# jquery to get the id of first parent div with an id attribute

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div>
   <div id="test">
     <div>
       <div>
         <div>
           <div id="SomeDiv">
```

Now suppose I have `TheDiv = $('#SomeDiv');` and that from there, I want to get the id of the first parent div that has an id, in this case `"test"`.

What's the best way to loop through parents to find an ID with jquery?

Thanks.

Comment: Might want to check out [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done with the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) selector

```
$("#SomeDiv").closest("div[id]");
```

Comment: functions like html(), hide() it is are not applicable to the results. Why?

Answer (score 1):

use `.parents('[id]')`. and get the first object eg.

```
TheDiv = $('#SomeDiv');
firstDivParent = TheDiv.parents('[id]')[0];
```

Comment: But now it will get any element with an `id` value that is a parent.  I think the question was for `div` elements only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
$("div#SomeDiv").closest("div[id]")
```

Or Alternately

```
$("div#SomeDiv").parents("div[id]")
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: But `closest` is better in this case because it returns only one element and stops when it finds one. Whereas `parents` will continue til it reaches the document level, and collect all elements matching the criteria.

Comment: @ahren for that you can just do `$("div#SomeDiv").parents("div[id]:first")` or replace `parents` with `parent` like: `$("div#SomeDiv").parent("div[id]")`

Comment: Why would you bother with that? It's redundant and verbose. The `closest` method is there for this purpose. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

var firstParent = TheDiv.parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
Each time you use a parent (), he climbs an div.